# Can connect to Oracle DB with pyodc in Anaconda but not in local py script

Tags: python, oracle, pyodbc

```
conn_CPO = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Oracle in OraCli193};DBQ=BLABLA;Uid=userid;Pwd=password')
curs_CPO = conn_CPO.cursor()
MVS_CPO = pd.read_sql(sql_query, conn_CPO)
curs_CPO.close()
```

I get this error:

```
conn_CPO = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Oracle in OraCli193};DBQ=blabla;Uid=userid;Pwd=password')
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][Gestionnaire de pilotes ODBC] 
Data source not found and driver name not specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

My script works in Anaconda but doesn't in local (Exact same script with the same import)

Comment: my bad just copy/past sorry.

Comment: Source de données introuvable et nom de pilote non spécifié = Data source not found and driver name not specified

Comment: I think the problem is due to the windows envrironment variable